# RegEx para filtrar palavras, desde que não estejam contidas em outras palavras

Tags: regex

Estou tentando criar um RegEx que filtra por certas palavras, para ser utilizado na validação do nome digitado pelo usuário em uma conversa com um chatbot. Como se trata de filtrar palavrões, troquei os mesmos por `palavraox`, para que esta pergunta não ficasse ofensiva.

O que consegui fazer até agora é:

```regex
/^((?!palavrao1|palavrao2|palavrao3|Palavrao1|Palavrao2|Palavrao3|PALAVRAO1|PALAVRAO2|PALAVRAO3).)*$/
```

O problema é, se uma pessoa tiver o nome que contém algum destes palavrões, ela será filtrada. No caso, o nome "Cuca" não seria válido pelo exato motivo.

Então gostaria de saber como seria para procurar pelo palavrão literalmente, não apenas se o nome contém tais palavrões.

Obs: Sei que é possível usar a *flag* `/i` para tornar o RegEx case-insensitive, mas o chatbot infelizmente não aceita estas *flags*.

Comment: Use o _Word Boundary_, o famoso `\b(palavra)\b`. Ele irá fazer com que a palavra não seja parte de outra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode trocar a regex para:

```
/^((?!\b(palavrao1|palavrao2|palavrao3)\b).)+$/
```

Eu agrupei todas as alternativas entre parênteses, e em torno delas coloquei `\b`, que é o [atalho para *word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (algo como "fronteira entre palavras"): basicamente, indica uma posição em que há um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa.

Assim, a regex só vai considerar o palavrão quando ele for uma palavra completa. Se ele só fizer parte de uma palavra (como em "Cuca"), a regex desconsidera.

Claro que ainda não vai evitar todos os casos: a pessoa ainda pode se chamar João Pinto, por exemplo, e seu sistema irá barrar (caso "Pinto" esteja na lista de palavrões). [Sempre haverá um caso em que o filtro falha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). [Sempre](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/).

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/IZesJ3/3/) um exemplo da regex rodando <sup>*(com palavrões)*</sup>.

---

Vale lembrar que esta regex se aplica a qualquer tipo de palavra, não apenas palavrões (afinal, pode-se colocar quaisquer palavras na lista).

Comment: Não acho que a última palavra no seu exemplo de palavrões seja realmente um palavrão. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @CypherPotato Mesmo estando em um link externo, eu não quis pegar pesado demais nos exemplos :-)

Comment: Coloca ancap nos exemplos. Eu me sinto ofendido quando me chamam assim.